# Selendroid setup in Android Studio

Tags: android, setup-deployment, selendroid

Can I use to test my application using Selendroid by writing the test case in Android Studio. I couldn't find much examples and tutorials for the implementation for Android Studio. I've refer to these website for the initial setup:

1. selendroid.io/setup.html
2. http://www.ontestautomation.com/up-and-running-with-selendroid/

What about the implementation in Android Studio? I tried adding into the "libs" folder:
1. selendroid­client­0.15.0.jar
2. selendroid­standalone­0.15.0­with­dependencies.jar

This error appeared:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Please advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your android studio project got to app-> libs and paste your selendroid specific jars in this.
2. add junit.4.12 jar lib as well and add this in app-> build.gradle -> inside dependencies ->
   testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
3. Then sync the build.
4. Create a Test Class in Src -> Main ->
5. For running test case first start selendroid sever-> open Build Variant and select Unit Tests.
   Now you can run your tests.